# need a word for something that can't be confessed

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word for something that can't be confessed 
or, in a more general way, something secret about you or someone else, that you wouldn't normally want the world to know about (if they know it comes from you, but you have no problem sharing it anonymously).

but not something like unspeakable (evil or bad).

It might be like a positive thing to say, but you can't just say it because you are afraid what other people might think of you.

Is there any other word, besides unconfessable, that can describe the above?

edit: found out the word unmentionable

Comment: unconfessable??

Comment: seems legit :P waiting to see if something shorter comes up :D

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You need to correct the first sentence as *shrift* and *let* don't work that way. *Think* should be *thing*, *cant* to *can't*. I tried to edit it, but decided not to.

Comment: thank you for your comments, will try to edit them so it works better:) what i meant for shrift, was to be seen as an example

Comment: Wow, tell us all about it!

Comment: tell us about it sounds good :P but was looking for something shorter, and more rear in the english language :)

Comment: Religiously, you might or might not believe in confession… and what else could be relevant, please?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest ***guilty***, as in *guilty pleasure*.

> guilty
>
> : suggesting or involving guilt [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/guilty)
>
> : suggesting or entailing guilt: *a guilty secret*. [American Heritage® Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/guilty)

Alternately, consider ***embarrassing [secret]***

> embarrass:  to cause to experience a state of self-conscious distress [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/embarrassing)

Comment: That definition of guilty is pretty useless. Unless you already know what guilt means. I'd add the definition of "guilty pleasure" instead as seems closer related to what the OP is asking than guilty is.

Comment: @MartinSmith But OP is after an adjective, not a phrase. "Is there any other word, besides unconfessable, that can describe the above?"

Comment: Both good suggestions, guilt partially describes what i want. but sometimes what you cant tell (untellable, unsharable,unconfessable etc) might not be because of guilt for something. but rather you can't expose something for someone else (either good "those two are dating" either bad "he stole food") because you don't want your name to be involved (you might also date one of two, or you could have participated in the theft, or you might just want justice to be served) .
In a more generall way, a word to describe the concept of something that it is impossible to tell, share or confess to others

Comment: @DiamantatosParaskevas "shameful?"

Answer (score 0):

Consider **shameful secret**.

> "Shameful" definition: full of the painful feeling arising from the
>   consciousness of something dishonorable, improper, ridiculous, etc.
>
> Example: *It is considered a sign of bad manners to ask a woman her
>   age, almost as if she were obliged to reveal a shameful secret*.